# Can light from the same source interfere with itself without utilizing n-slit screens?

Tags: visible-light, photons, double-slit-experiment, interference

I was wondering - can a source produce light which travels in such a configuration that part of it travels a longer distance (i.e., is out of phase with its other part) thus exhibiting an interference pattern?

Does this always require some kind of double (or more) slit, or rather, is such a slit required for my above example?

In addition: is it possible for a *single* photon to interact with itself without the use of a double slit (for example, in a perfecty reflective closed system or if part of the light would be dispersed)?

Comment: A photon is a state of a quantum field. You can only determine this state by making a measurement, so you are essentially dealing with one photon at A, where you prepare an initial state by emitting it from a light source, and then you find a second photon at B, where your detector is. There are in the free space case, strictly speaking, no photons because there are no measurements. If you were to do multiple measurements between A and B, then you would see additional photons, but you would also "fog up" space and the time development of the system would be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example you can use partially [silvered mirrors or some other form of beam splitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter) to split a light beam onto two paths then recombine the two paths again to produce interference.

This works even with a single photon. The beam splitters put the photon into a superposition of the two paths.

Answer (score 1):

Another example which mimics a two-slit experiment, but using one slit and a mirror (the interference pattern is phase shifted compared with the two slit experiment) is Lloyd's Mirror.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_mirror

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use [birefringent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence) materials to create two separate beams from a common source.